# Would this question about the Deck of Many Things be allowed?

Tags: discussion, questions, subjective-questions, workshop-question

I recently asked [this question on the Deck of Many Things](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/205466/deck-of-many-things-how-problematic-is-each-card-for-a-campaign) which was closed as opinion-based. I would like to revisit the topic and ask for expert opinion from a different angle.

To avoid as much controversy on the main site as the other question caused, I would like to submit the for review here before posting it (or refraining from doing so).

I would like to ask a question along the lines of: "What concrete negative consequences does the Deck of Many Things usually have on a campaign causing its reputation as *campaign killer*?"

I feel like this question is not opinion-based but would like to hear your takes on the matter - that's what this post is for. **Is that question stackable?**

Comment: Is that the actual question you have, or is that the question think might be stackable? It might be better to begin with telling us what you're trying to know and possibly why/what that info will do.

Comment: Actually, based on your previous question, I think we do know that - and the previous answer also kind of answered it.

Comment: @NautArch I don't want to ruin my so I would like to know what bad might happen when I use the deck as is, so I can avoid it.

Comment: Are you still unsure after reviewing the deck yourself? A good question could be following up on the specific card(s), if any, that you're not sure about and why.

Comment: @NautArch For some cards I have a pretty good idea. Both cards that I am pretty sure will cause problems and ones where I doubt anything bad would happen. So I could ask more specific questions as well about the remaining cards.

Comment: One direction your pre-question research might take is to look at media where people describe the deck breaking the game, see what cards were responsible, and ask how that card could be implemented/tweaked to avoid the sort of problem it caused in that recorded instance.

Comment: I don't understand how this is an improvement on the previous twice-closed question.

Comment: To clarify:  Just specifying "concrete negative consequences" in the question does not remove the bad-subjective qualities of it, in my mind.

Answer (score 9):

### No, it would not.

Your updated question doesn't fundamentally change the opinion-based issue that has closed your initial question. What is a concrete negative consequence is still going to be opinion-based as there has to be general agreement about it which there likely isn't.

### What you can do

What you can do is step back and don't worry about finding a more generic question that may be helpful for *others*. It's okay to focus on your needs and it's actually easier for you to elucidate your problem and what you're looking for.

I'd begin with a self-analysis of the cards as they are. You know yourself, your players, and your table better than we do and you'll be able to identify cards that might be problematic for you.

The next step is the meat of the problem: figuring out your question. What is your goal with the analysis? Do you want to 'fix' cards? Avoid them? Something else? Figuring out how you want to the deck to work will help determine how we can answer and give you more targeted answers for your specific needs.

The key is being in clear in your requirements, goals, and concerns you see with a particular card.